# Only targeting iPhone/iPod touch after previous universal binary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Please bear with me, this isn't a programming question per se but a question about releasing for the App Store.

I have an App on the store that is a universal binary, with a separate UI for the iPad.  I've been creating some new features and working exclusively in the iPhone version.  I've been rethinking my iPad UI because I feel like it's kind of poor and could be more well done.  I'd like to branch off and create a specialized iPad only version and abandon the iPad code in the current universal binary, and instead just target the individual platforms instead of both.

The reasons are as follows:

I want to be able to do a release with new features without having to commit to working them all in on the iPad version of the universal binary.

I want to distinguish the iPad version from the iPhone version.

First, I want to know if this is even possible.  Second, I want to know what kind of fallout is possible from something like this.  I remember two years ago when Tweetie 2 was a new bundle and the general public mostly whined about having to pay again.  My app is much smaller than Tweetie 2 and I don't have a ton of users.  In fact, I don't use any analytics to discover daily use, feature use, or anything.

Have any of you ever done something like this?

Thanks for your time, and please don't flag.

Answer (score 0):

That would really suck for iPad-only users who bought your program.

What you could do is leave the existing app out there as version 1. Don't upgrade it.

Release version 2 in separate iPhone and iPad flavours. No existing customer gets left out. You get to split your releases. If your app is truly good then people will pay again for the upgraded version.